# c# How to implement disposition type (Inline //or Attachment) for PostMark provider

Tags: c#, email-attachments, postmark

**SMTP Provider C# Code:**

```
MailMessage Mail;

Mail.Attachments.Clear();

Byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strICSData);

var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);

var a = new Attachment(ms, "meeting111.ics", "text/calendar");

a.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;

Mail.Attachments.Add(a);
```

Here 
`a.ContentDisposition.Inline`
 Gets or sets a System.Boolean value that determines the disposition type (Inline or Attachment) for an e-mail attachment.

Above code is working fine and mapping my meeting to outlook calendar as shown below.

Find smtp screen shot after sending mail :[image]

**Postmark Provider C# Code:**

I am also using postmark provider for mail but i did not find any `a.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;` functionality.

Please find the below Postmark code :

```
PostmarkMessage message;

message.Attachments.Clear();

byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strICSData);

var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);

message.AddAttachment(ms, "meeting111.ics", "text/calendar");

Below line, Adds a file stream with inline support:
message.AddAttachment(ms, "meeting.ics", "text/calendar");
```

Can anybody provide me solution so that postmark attachment is going to map to outlook calendar.

Comment: In order to get better outlook compatibility through our API, you'll need to set the ContentID for the attachment like the following:

attachment.ContentID = "cid:meeting.ics"

Answer (score 1):

In order to get better outlook compatibility through our API, you'll need to set the ContentID for the attachment like the following:

attachment.ContentID = "cid:meeting.ics"

So we have to **change**
message.AddAttachment(ms, "meeting.ics", "text/calendar");

**TO**
message.AddAttachment(ms, "meeting.ics", "text/calendar","cid:meeting.ics");